# C# struct with enum For Form Position

Tags: c#, struct, enums

I have an enum and struct as shown below.

`public enum appedges{Left = 0, Top = 1,Right = 2, Bottom = 3}`

`public struct edges{ public int X, Y, wide, len;}`

This struct has been declared/instantiated Four times(LeftEdge,RightEdge,TopEdge,BottomEdge) with the values being set for all its members. Based on the button Onclick events a certain value of the enum would be chosen. And Based on that, i need to choose one of the declared struct instances to set the Form properties like shown below:

so if the enum value chosen was "Top", then

```
if (_side == appedges.Top)
{
    this.Location = new Point(TopEdge.X, TopEdge.Y);
    this.Height = TopEdge.len;
    this.Width = TopEdge.wide; 
}
```

Similarly, for other values of the enum(Left, Bottom, Right...) , i would have to write the same "IF" loop with different struct instances.

I think there might be an easy way to accomplish this. I mean like, Generalising the way the struct instances are used. I don't want to set Form properties everytime for every single "IF" loop . I hope you guys understood my point.

I am a newbie to c#. So, i am struggling with this. If you can help,that would be great!!

ThankYou:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a dictionary where you initialize an `Edge` per `AppEdge`:

```
var positions = new Dictionary<AppEdge, Edge>
{
    { AppEdge.Left, new Edge { X = 0, Y = 0, ... } },
    { AppEdge.Top, new Edge { X = 0, Y = 0, ... } },
    { AppEdge.Right, new Edge { X = 0, Y = 0, ... } },
    { AppEdge.Bottom, new Edge { X = 0, Y = 0, ... } },
};
```

Then use the `_side` as index to look up `Edge`s in that dictionary:

```
var edge = positions[_side];
this.Location = new Point(edge.X, edge.Y);
this.Height = edge.len;
this.Width = edge.wide;
```

And given you're new to C#, take a look at the [naming guidelines for C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Awesome :) I knew about the dictionaries before..but didn't think i could use it this way. Thanks For the Help. Really Appreciate !!